# Curl error (6) with a local address behind vagrant

Tags: curl, vagrant

I'm getting an error when trying to curl on nameserver pointing to a local IP from a vagrant machine; how could I resolve it?

```
vagrant@scotchbox:~$ curl -XGET http://rpic-remixmyenergy.local/sample.html
```

So vagrant use an adress on a different network 192.168.33.x and couldn't resolve a dns on my local network ? 192.168.1.x

On my local machine, there is no problem.

Comment: do you are using private_network? Do you can post your Vagrantfile and error?

Comment: yes, 192.168.33.x is the private network, it's a curl error that couldn't resolve my dns address on my local network 192.168.1.x

Answer (score 0):

What's the error?
AFAIK you're using NAT (to get 192.168.33.x in the VM) since your host is 192.168.1.x

What you'd want to do is bridge if that is your expectation. NAT has some limitations based on the host, which is acting as a router.